# API call using Mongoose .find() with filter not returning anything?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

The strangest thing started happening today. An otherwise working API call using Mongoose/Node suddenly stopped returning results. I tested the call in Insomnia as well, returns no data, but no errors either. As I mentioned, it worked prior... here's the Node and React blocks:

Node.js:

```
router.route('/top/:category').get((req, res) => {
    Whiskey.find({ category: req.params.category }).sort({ rated: -1 }).limit(3)
        .then(whiskies => res.json(whiskies))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

React Hook calling it:

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`http://localhost:5000/whiskies/top/${capitalize(category)}`)
        axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/whiskies/top/${capitalize(category)}`)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.data.length > 0) {
                    setWhiskies(res.data)
                    console.log(res.data)
                } else {
                    console.log("No items")
                }
            })
    }, [])
```

Something I found while attempting to debug: if you remove the filter from `.find()` the API call works. I have not changed anything on the front-end regarding the call, either.

Comment: please check your MongoDB service status is running or not.

Comment: It is. As I mentioned, the API call works sans filter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line, `${capitalize(category)}`.

You are capitalizing the category name in the url and sending it to the node api.

Please either send the `category` as it is or make it to lowercase in the backend before submitting it to the query.

Use the following.

```
let categoryName = req.params.category;
Whiskey.find({ category: categoryName.toLowerCase() }).sort({ rated: -1 }).limit(3)
```

Hope this will work. Thanks